# Migrate azure sql database to Azure SQL Database Managed Instance

Tags: azure-sql-database

We need to migrate one of the database into MI from Azure Sql. Has anyone done it before.Looking for any documenatation/Guidance on this as not much is available. Will be testing the below method soon.

One way would be to import the bacpac to blob and then use to restore in the MI. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by managed instance? Physical named instance?

Comment: @CR241 : SQL Database Managed Instance.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Managed Instance was in preview, the first option we have is to export your Azure SQL Database as a bacpac then import that bacpac to your Managed Instance.

A better option we have now is using the Azure Data Migration service. It is not only faster than the method I described above, but it gives you the option to perform a data validation at end and it rebuilds all indexes on the database. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-managed-instance?wt.mc_id=MVP) you have a step-by-step tutorial.

Comment: I think these are the only 2 ways. Will mark it as answer if i do not find any other way.

Comment: To my knowledge these are the only two methods to migrate from Azure SQL Database. The Data Migration Assistant does not support Azure SQL Database as a source. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

Comment: @Shanky Native SQL Server backups are not available on Azure SQL Database DTU model and vCore Model. They are available on Managed Instance.